# How to create Horizontal (inline) Menu bar in custom home page of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming

i am new to wordpress. i want to customize a page in wordpress where i want to create a Horizontal menu bar but after trying all posible ways still i am not able to make a hozizontal bar. it is look like below image

[Menu bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcVNg.jpg)

```css
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fourteen
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen/
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
*/

body
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}


ul.Menu
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top:0.8%;
    padding: 3%;
 text-decoration:none;
 float:right;
 font-size:18px;
 font-family:Lato-Regular;
 margin-right:20%;
 position:relative;
 background-color:#A52A2A;
 display:inline-block;
}

li.Menu
{
    display: inline-block;
 padding:15px;
}

ul li a.Menu 
{
 color:#32445A;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div>
<ul class="Menu">
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#home"><img src="http://10.37.4.179/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/home-active.png" alt="home"></a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Features & Benefits">Features & Benefits</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Support">Support</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Training">Training</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#What's New">What's New</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="active" href="#Aboutus">About Us</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

please help me to create a horizontal inline menu bar for my custom home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're targeting the wrong class on the `li`s. Should be:

```
ul.Menu li.list {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

You also don't have the class `Menu` on your links, so that CSS is wrong and should be:

```
ul.Menu a.ListClass  {
  color: #32445A;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Finally, you probably want your `ul` to be `display: block` to automatically take 100% width.

```
ul.Menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top:0.8%;
    padding: 3%;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Lato-Regular;
    margin-right:20%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#A52A2A;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: still not working sir . could you please suggest me full css for this

Answer (score 0):

Is that you want?

```css
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fourteen
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen/
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
*/

body
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}


ul.Menu
{
    list-style-type:none;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:18px;
 font-family:Lato-Regular;
 margin-right:20%;
 position:relative; 
 display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

li.Menu
{
    display: inline-block;
 
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    width:14.2%;
}

ul li a
{
 color:#32445A;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<body <?php body_class(); ?>

<div>
<ul class="Menu">
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#home"><img src="http://10.37.4.179/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/home-active.png" alt="home"></a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Features & Benefits">Features & Benefits</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Support">Support</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Training">Training</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#What's New">What's New</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="active" href="#Aboutus">About Us</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what i am getting . i want a horizontal inline menu bar .

Comment: got it..wait for min

Comment: sir this is coming in 3*3 row-column, not in-line and i want to remove these bullets before all menu option

Comment: see it with full page

Comment: you want full responsive all resolution in one line??

Comment: @SagarKodte Where are the `li`s with the class `Menu`??

Comment: Can you review my edit on your answer @SagarKodte and Arpit Gupta

Comment: actually i want to know OP's requirement till that i can't

Comment: just need to edit in css what you and Arpit wants it might be get with a simple change in css where `li.Menu { display:inline-block;}` just rearrange the class by `.Menu li { display:inline-block;}` and remove `width:135px;` from `ul li` also.